# How can i do this gallery with bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, html

i have a homework that is to replicate the car brand page so i got stuck on this part..

[image]

I'm trying to replicate that gallery with .container and nested rows but i can't get it, this is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <figure class="col-6">
                  <img src="img/img8.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
              </figure>
              <div class="col-6">
                  <div class="row">
                      <figure class="col-12">
                          <img class="col-5" src="img/img13.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                          <img class="col-5" src="img/img10.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                          <img class="col-5" src="img/img13.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                          <img class="col-5" src="img/img10.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">  
                      </figure>                    
                    </div>            
                </div>
              </div>                                                                        
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern, I think it helps.

```
<div class="container main">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
           <img src="yours" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block">
        </div>
        <div class="row col-sm-6">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <img src="yours" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <img src="yours" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <img src="yours" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <img src="yours" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```